# How to obtain the physical coordinates of the nodes in an ITK :: Mesh obtained from a 3D volume of ct images

Tags: itk

I am using ITK library to get a mesh from a 3D image, the 3D image is a volume of slices. I get the mesh using **itk::BinaryMask3DMeshSource**. But I need to get its physical coordinate for each mesh node and I don't know how to do it.
I know how to obtain with ITK the physical coordinate of a voxel in a image using the **TransformIndexToPhysicalPoint** function. But when I have a mesh like this or an ITK::Mesh I don't know how to do it. I need to know if there is any relationship between the nodes of the mesh and the voxels in the image to find the physical coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh points should already be in physical space, judging by both [the code and the accompanying comment](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/4c0982ddec474b1701d695839c78c7e888659ef4/Modules/Core/Mesh/include/itkBinaryMask3DMeshSource.hxx#L2409-L2413).